# Are "Gods" indestructible even when they are not yet creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

As long as the card [Nylea, Keen-Eyed](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNylea%2c%20Keen-Eyed%5d) -
(or the parallel red card, or [Purphoros, Bronze-Blooded](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPurphoros%2c%20Bronze-Blooded%5d), or [Athreos, Shroud-Veiled](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAthreos%2c%20Shroud-Veiled%5d), or other specular cards, often with the subtype "God") -
is not yet a creature, since his devotion to the indicated color has not yet reached the sufficient value, does he still possess the indestructible ability? I'll explain better.

For example, since it's a card that's also an enchantment, could it be destroyed by a Disenchant as long as it's not a creature; or is the indestructible ability active even when it's not yet a creature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, the Enchantment Gods are always indestructible, whether or not they are creatures.**

When the Gods stop being a creature due to insufficient Devotion, the only things they lose are the creature type, the creature-related subtype (*God*), and their power and toughness. Abilities of that object are not affected, even if they are abilities that wouldn't make sense on a non-creature, such as Trample. However, Indestructible isn't even a creature-only ability, as there are non-creatures with that ability, such as [Darksteel Relic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDarksteel%20Relic%5d).

> 208.3. A noncreature permanent has no power or toughness, even if it’s a card with a power and toughness printed on it (such as a Vehicle). [..]
>
> 205.1a [..] If an object’s card type is removed, the subtypes correlated with that card type will remain if they are also the subtypes of a card type the object currently has; otherwise, they are also removed for the entire time the object’s card type is removed. [..]

Answer (score 5):

As Gatherer says on each of the Gods you link to, as well as any other such God:

> The abilities of Gods function as long as they’re on the battlefield, regardless of whether they’re creatures.

So the indestructible ability still works when your devotion is too low.